# Using floats when working with sympy circles

Tags: python, sympy

I'm having some trouble understanding the way floats are interpreted in sympy. I can print the point test center as floats, but when I use it in a circle it gives me rational numbers.

```
test_center=Point (1.03, 2.76, evaluate=False)
test_circle = Circle (test_center, 1, evaluate=False)

When I print them I get:

Point2D(1.03, 2.76)
Circle(Point2D(103/100, 69/25), 1)
```

How can I print the circle center as a float? Thanks!